# creating variables from external data in python script

Tags: python, scripting

I want to read an external data source (excel) and create variables containing the data.  Suppose the data is in columns and each column has a header with the variable name.

My first idea is to write a function so i can easily reuse it.  Also, I could easily give some additional keyword arguments to make the function more versatile.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to refer to the data in python (interactively) via the variable names.  I don't know how to do that (with a function).  The only solution I see is returning the variable names and the  data from my function (eg as lists), and do something like this:

```
def get_data()
    (...)
    return names, values

names, values = get_data(my_excel)

for n,v in zip(names, values):
    exec(''.join([n, '= v']))
```

Can I get the same result directly?
Thanks,
Roel

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  Choosing THE accepted answer is difficult as you all contributed and learned me things.  I finally chose to use the 'object' approach of @lazyr as it gives me most easy access to my data (moreover, the Ipython console can automatically complete the attributes, so really practical!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set local variables for each name in names, use:

```
for n, v in zip(names, values):
    locals()[n] = v
```

If you'd rather like to have a single object to access the data, which is much cleaner, simply use a dict, and return that from your function.

```
def get_data():
    (...)
    return dict(zip(names, values))
```

To access the value of the name "a", simply use `get_data()["a"]`.

Finally, if you want to access the data as attributes of an object, you can update the `__dict__` of an object (unexpected behaviour may occur if any of your column names are equal to any [special python methods](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/specialnames.html)).

```
class Data(object):
   def __init__(self, my_excel):
       (...)
       self.__dict__.update(zip(names, values))

data = Data("test.xls")
print data.a
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.  Updating the locals looks like a nice trick to have the data at hand for scripting without having to type data.a all the time.

Comment: Is that really a problem, though? You only have to type 'data.' a few times while you're writing your program the first time, and then you're done with it for life. In exchange, you *know* that data.foo isn't going to interfere with your "real" variable foo.

Comment: Well, it's because i want to make graphs and such interactively, like one would do in a matlab command window. This requires typing the variables rather often. But indeed, it's not a real issue when i can use the object approach as showed above.  It's much easier than dictionaries: `data.a` instead of `data['a']`

Comment: Have you tried your example with `locals()`? It doesn't work here (Python 2.7), and [the documentation says it doesn't work](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals).

Comment: Yes, it works (Python 2.6).  I am using the object approach of lazyr with `data = Data("my_excel")` and I updated locals like this: ´locals().update(data.__dict__)´

Comment: @Baffe My bad, I just tried it in the console and it worked, should have checked the docs (and read [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/dialect_locals.html)). It should obviously not be used in production, but if it works for saroele and it's only for personal use, why not.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to store your mapping from name to value instead of creating local variable.

```
def get_data(excel_document):
    mapping = {}
    mapping['name1'] = 'value1'
    # ...
    return mapping

mapping = get_data(my_excel)
for name, value in mapping:
    # use them
```

If you really want to populate variables from the mapping, you can modify `globals()` (or `locals()`), but it is generally considered bad practice.

```
mapping = get_data(my_excel)
globals().update(mapping)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  You say updating globals() is considered bad practice.  The answer from @lazyr seems to do the same but with locals, which looks like a good intermediate solution, or is this considered bad practice too?

Comment: Changing `locals()` is also frequently considered bad practice since, you can't easily deduce what variables are defined just by reading the code (this is worse when updating `globals()`). This goes against the principle of least surprise and will render the code harder to understand. If this is just for a small script, then it is probably fine, but for larger application, you should consider other alternatives.

Comment: I guess in this case I can live with it: I want to use the variables in matlab-like way to make graphs in a try/error approach.  It's just easier to type plt.plot(Temp1) than plt.plot(d.Temp1) (if d is the dictionary).  (BTW, how do I format code in this comment section?)

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach would be to stuff the key/value pairs into a dict so that you can easily pass the whole structure around to other functions. If you really want to store them as attributes instead of dict keys, consider creating a class to hold them:

```
class Values(object): pass
store = Values()
for key, value in zip(names, values):
    setattr(store, key, value)
```

That keeps the variables in their own namespace, separate from your running code. That's almost always a Good Thing. What if you get a spreadsheet with a header called "my_excel"? Suddenly you've lost access to your original `my_excel` object, which would be very inconvenient if you needed it again.

But in any case, you should never use `exec` unless you know exactly what you're doing. And even then, don't use `exec`. For instance, I know how your code works and send you a spreadsheet with `"os.system('echo rm -rf *')"` in a cell. You probably don't really want to execute that.

Comment: That's a clear example why using exec can be dangerous indeed.  I don't know what your code does, but i suppose I don't want to try :-)

Comment: Well, /this one/ is just a harmless little print statement so that I couldn't be blamed if someone copied-and-pasted to see if it really worked. :-)